# Does this set have Schnirelmann density $0$?

Tags: number-theory

I am a bit confused about Schnirelmann densities in some cases. Recall that if $X$ denotes a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then the Schnirelmann density of $X$ is defined as
$$
\sigma X = \inf_n \frac{\pi(n)}{n},
$$
i.e., the greatest lower bound of the fractions $\frac{\pi(n)}{n}$, where $\pi(n)$ is the number of terms in $X$ below $n$.

Now let's say I have a set $X$ that includes $\{1\}$ and has natural density $0$, with something like $\pi(n)\sim \log(n)$. Does $X$ also have Schnirelmann density $0$?

---

The reason I'm confused is because the Schnirelmann density is highly sensitive to the first values of $\pi(n)$, and I've heard somewhere that if $\{1\}\in X$ then the Schnirelmann density is most of the time not equal to $0$.

But in this specific case, since $\frac{\pi(n)}{n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, it would seem to me that the ''*greatest lower bound of the fractions $\frac{\pi(n)}{n}$*'' is $0$, and the Schnirelmann density is $0$ as well even though $\{1\}$ is part of the set.

Am I right? Or is this completely wrong?